# SQL SELECT query with two tables containing sum function

Tags: sql, select, hana

How can I get, in a single SELECT query, a result from two tables, one of which contains SUM function ?

Table **SALARY**

| EMPLOYEE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1000 |
| Bob | 2000 |
| Phill | 4000 |
| John | 500 |
| Bob | 1000 |
| Bob | 100 |

Table **ADRESS**

| EMPLOYEE | CITY |
| --- | --- |
| John | LA |
| Bob | NYC |
| Phill | LA |

Expected result:

| EMPLOYEE | CITY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | LA | 1500 |
| Bob | NYC | 3100 |
| Phill | LA | 4000 |

I know how to get the sum of salaries:

```
select EMPLOYEE, SUM(AMOUNT) from SALARY group by EMPLOYEE
```

But I don't know how to combine the result with the ADDRESS table.

I tried this :

```
select S.EMPLOYEE, SUM(S.AMOUNT), A.city from SALARY S, ADDRESS A 
group by S.EMPLOYEE
```

**=> "not a GROUP BY expression: 'A.CITY' must be in group by clause"**

So I added A.CITY in the group by clause :

```
select S.EMPLOYEE, SUM(S.AMOUNT), A.city from SALARY S, ADDRESS A group by S.EMPLOYEE, A.city
```

Which gave me this result :

| EMPLOYEE | SUM(AMOUNT) | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3000 | LA |
| John | 1500 | NYC |
| Bob | 3100 | NYC |
| Phill | 8000 | LA |
| Bob | 6200 | LA |
| Phill | 4000 | NYC |

Comment: Regarding editting the question, for some reason the tables need a blank line above them to render correctly in the question, but the "preview" shows the tables correctly without the additional blank line. I've edited the question and added the blank lines so they show up correctly.

Comment: You failed to supply a join criteria in your `FROM` clause. A good rule to follow is to never use a comma to separate tables in your FROM. Join then correctly: `from SALARY S INNER JOIN ADDRESS A on S.Employee = A.Employee`. Replace your FROM clause in your last SQL attempt and rerun. By using a comma and not supplying join conditions, you were having your database join every row in `SALARY` with every row in `ADDRESS`.

Comment: @JNevill And I get your point about never use separate tables in the FROM, but use a JOIN instead.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

select S.EMPLOYEE,A.City, SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS Amount from SALARY S
JOIN Address A on S.EMPLOYEE = A.EMPLOYEE group by S.EMPLOYEE,A.City;

Answer (score 0):

try this?

select S.EMPLOYEE, SUM(S.AMOUNT), A.city
from SALARY S
join ADDRESS A on A.EMPLOYEE=S.EMPLOYEE
group by S.EMPLOYEE, A.city